# Момент по проектированию БД

Tags: база-данных, проектирование, firebird

Ситуация следущая:
Имеется несколько отделов и *плановый* отдел.
Все отделы имеют право состовлять договора, но только плановый может назначать уже сделанным договорам номера (поле «number») и если что отправлять их в архив (статут «архив» поле «archive»).

Т.к. большинство полей совпадает, то у меня все договора по всем отделам в том числе и планового, содержатся в одной таблице.

Наверняка, в процессе работы с БД, появятся коллизии в плане редактирования одной и той же записи в одно время обычным и плановым отделом.
Например когда обычный отдел редактирует свой договор, а плановый отдел захочет присвоить ему номер, то сохранится та запись (того dataset), которая позже сохранилась, или такая же ситуация может произойти с редактированием поля «archive».

Для избежания таких ситуаций (с одновременным доступом к одной той же записи), мне наверно нужно перенести общие поля (такие как «number» и «archive») в другую таблицу с конкретным ID записи конечно.

Вопрос:
Это правильный выход, чтоб избежать этой ситуации? Или есть еще вариант?

Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Человек из планового отдела может редактировать только номер? Будет очень странно, если он найдет опечатку в договоре и поправит ее, присвоит номер, нажмет сохранить и по итогу опечатка останется. По идее данные можно не разносить, а сделать два разных View. В глобальном плане есть вариант сделать таблицу Lock(userID int, DocID int) и запретить редактировать документ двум людям одновременно, но с этим надо быть осторожным, что бы не залочить документ навсегда.

Comment: Выносить в отдельную таблицу номер точно нет никакой необходимости. Вы можете давать update номера договора не затрагивая остальные поля и в случае, если все находится в одной таблице

Comment: @Alex Krass, пока знаю что плановый точно может редактировать номер договора и поле статуса архива, про другие поля пока не знаю (все на совести других отделов)...

Comment: @Mike, ваше предложение пока более примечательнее, т.е. я так понял в DataSet нужно отредактировать свойство "ModifySQL" а именно убрать из него "номер договора" и "статус архива"... Но в таком случае я боюсь забвать при последующих генерации запросов в самом DataSet, отдельно редактировать в ручную запрос "ModifySQL". Или его придется автоматически генерировать при загрузке приложения?

Comment: Не представляю что такое ваш DataSet. возможно стоит указать язык разработки клиентской части. Я же говорю только с точки зрения БД, потому что про нее вы и спрашиваете. И что то мне подсказывает, что если тот кому доступно редактирование поля нажмет в таком dataset запись, он перепишет и остальные поля. что возможно то же не правильно, потому что другие поля в это время может править кто то другой.

Comment: @Mike, Я имел ввиду "TIBDataSet" для просмотра и модификации набора записей (с вкладки "InterBase" (Delphi)). В таком случае, при выборе "IBDataSet" записи отдела, если плановый отдел захочет вставить номер договора в такую запись, то в "TIBDataSet" я ему позволю редактировать/обновлять только поле "номер договора", т.е. в запросе на обновление, будет участвовать только поле "номер договора"